# Como puedo configurar Node y React con Apache?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, apache

Tengo un VPS donde instalé Apache, y tengo un app hecha con Node (express) y React el frontend.

Hice un build de React, y puse los archivos en /var/www/html , es el folder público que te genera Apache.

Hasta ahí todo bien, luego corro el servidor/backend de node con **npm run start**

El problema esque cuando accedo al frontend, no encuentra las rutas **dominio.com/api/v1/etc..**

Tengo el backendo corriendo con **localhost:4000** pero como que el frontend no encuentra eso.

En apache agregué un virtual host con la siguiente configuración:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ProxyRequests Off
         ProxyPreserveHost On
         ProxyVia Full
         <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
         </Proxy>

      <Location /api>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:4000
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4000
       </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Pensando que podía redirigir todas las peticiones que vayan de domain.com/api a localhost:4000 , el problema esque no funciona así tampoco, sin embargo si escribo domain.com/api como tal en mi web browser si me aparece Node

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, es la primera vez que tengo una app con Node en backend, nose como conectarla al frontend.
En mi entorno local funciona todo perfectamente.

Si en lugar de direccionar las peticiones de **/api a localhost:4000**
añado solo /, es decir la siguiente configuración:

```
 <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:4000
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4000
  </Location>
```

Ya no se ve el frontend de React y me dirige automáticamente a Node, osea la aplicación ya no se ve.

Comment: Tu servidor en node espera recibir pedidos a `/api/v1/ejemplo` o a `/v1/ejemplo`? Porque me parece que el Apache le quita el `/api` cuando hace el proxypass. Puedes probar poner `ProxyPass http://localhost:4000/api`

Comment: verifica que el frontend esté realmente haciendo la petición y no interceptando la url onda react router o similar, si se complica proba hacer el proxy/api con un subdominio onda apache en www.dominio.com y node en api.dominio.com

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes actualmente me toco trabajar con Ubuntu y Nginx el cual tiene un comportamiento muy parecido a Apache. Te dejo un gist con una implementación de ejemplo, espero que te sirva.

Saludos!

[Ubuntu + Nginx Hosting compartido](https://gist.github.com/pmNiko/c52138a22379ca68fbcf3d721f285aa9)

Edición de la respuesta en Apache httpd seria:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias www.domain
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/<react-app>
     ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/log/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/domain.com/log/requests.log combined


     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass /api  http://domain.com:4000/
     ProxyPassReverse /api  http://domain.com:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```

De esta manera deberias poder redirigir tus sitios. Para ver una descriptción mas completa puedes ingresar al siguiente gist en el cual se detalla como configurar Apache httpd en Centos 7.

[Apache httpd - Centos 7](https://gist.github.com/pmNiko/082848bf713bf332cec1219a89c46785)

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta. Está poderoso ese Gist, por lo que se ve. La cosa es que, si lo borras, tu cuenta deja de estar o lo cambias y deja de ser la respuesta a la pregunta, tu respuesta aquí deja de ser útil a otros que vengan en el futuro con la misma duda. Trata de [edit] y añadir al menos los puntos principales relevantes a la solución que compartes.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/356135)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).